# yarn build just hangs when completed

Tags: reactjs, build, yarnpkg

I thought i had figured out what the problem was but alas, i did not. When running my build script `yarn build` or even `npm run build` the script builds just fine but the process never completes and just hangs... Does anyone have an idea on how to go about troubleshooting this sort of problem?

here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "stars-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bulma": "^0.5.1",
    "custom-react-scripts": "0.2.0",
    "firebase": "^4.3.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-feather": "^1.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "styled-components": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start",
    "build": "NODE_PATH=src react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-tools": "^3.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to try out other version of yarn of npm

Comment: i suppose so. i opened an issue with them, we'll see if they have an idea

Comment: did you had news regarding that issue?

Comment: No. and now i'm back up against it... sigh